# Connecting Spring Batch to Remote Cassandra Database

Tags: spring-batch

I'm hoping to read data from a CSV file, process the data, and upload it to a remote database. I'm using Spring's starter repo as a [base](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/). Code is [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/tree/master/complete)

I tried putting this information in the properties file:

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=IP, IP
spring.data.cassandra.port=PORT
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=KEYSPACE_NAME
spring.data.cassandra.username=USER
spring.data.cassandra.password=PASS
spring.data.cassandra.ssl=TRUE
```

However, I think it keeps defaulting to pushing to some local tomcat jdbc. I'm not really sure where to start. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have anything to use Cassandra.  It doesn't have any of the dependencies and the `ItemWriter` implementation is a `JdbcBatchItemWriter` which I don't think will work for Cassandra.  You need to configure your application to actually use Cassandra (the spring data starter as well as an `ItemWriter` implementation that can write to Cassandra).